# TFS 2017/2018 Kanban board share and add parent link to cards

Tags: tfs

Found issues online but no solutions yet, and uservoice is down. I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to make a kanban board template and be able to use that in other projects? Ex. a team wants to create an additional project but wants all of their customization changes to be added to the new project (like board columns and rules).
2. When looking at the user story portfolio backlog kanban board, is there a way to add the parent link to each card?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1:

Unfortunately, for now there isn't such a feature in VSTS/TFS to share Kanban template across teams in a project.

There's already an user voice submitted to suggest the feature: [share kanban format across teams](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18851464-share-kanban-format-across-different-teams-in-a-pr), you can vote it and follow up there.

> Q2:

No, you cannot add the parent link to each card/wit, you can only open the specific work item (user story here) and add parent link manually.